# How to prevent terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalid' error in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I've a simple TableView with basic style cells. I fill it as follow

class MunicipalitiesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

```
var municipalities = [Municipality]()

@IBOutlet weak var municipalitiesTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let dbHelper = RaccoltacaseDbHelper()
    municipalities = dbHelper.getMunicipalities()

    municipalitiesTableView.dataSource = self
    municipalitiesTableView.delegate = self        
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filterMunicipalities(s: searchText)

    self.municipalitiesTableView.reloadData()
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {        
    return self.municipalities.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath)

    var municipality = Municipality()

    cell.textLabel?.text = municipality.value!

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let filterVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FilterViewController") as! FilterViewController

    var municipality = Municipality()
    if municipalitiesSearchBar.text != "" {
        municipality = filteredMunicipalities[indexPath.row]
    }
    else {
        municipality = municipalities[indexPath.row]
    }

    let search = Search()
    if (municipality.id == 0) {
        search.zoneId = municipality.province
        search.isMunicipality = false
    }
    else {
        search.zoneId = municipality.id
        search.isMunicipality = true
    }
    search.type = Search.ZONE_TAG

    filterVC.search = search

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(filterVC, animated: true)
}
```

}

Now, when I click on a row all work as expected but if I click on the cell separator app crashes with following error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalid', reason: 'layer  is a part of cycle in its layer tree'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't look like the problem is in the code posted.

Comment: @onnoweb so where it could be?